# Query on Workflow retry count

Tags: c#, .net, workflow

I am using DefaultWorkflowCommitWorkBatchService , some times the workflow is not persisted in the DB. It's an unknown error which I am trying to find via logging.

On the other hand, I know we can re try workflows by using EnableRetries property.

My Question:

According to msdn the count is fixed/hard coded to 20 ! . I need to know if somehow we can configure this counter, as 20 is too much and causes web timeout exceptions due to application design.

Links:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms732240(v=vs.90).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735941(v=vs.90).aspx

Any help/pointers on this would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks. To test this I have put a divide by zero error in the code, it retries for 20 times and then pass, but since before 20 retries I get web timeout exception.

I am using .net 2.0 webservices which Invokes the workflow.

Can we override the CommitWorkBatch method of class DefaultWorkflowCommitWorkBatchService  in our workflow code?.

Comment: I have found a solution for this. We can control the count by writing a custom workflowcommitworkbatch service class and add this in your web.config services section. You can write your own logic into it !

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the retry count can be changed. It's going to try 3 times back to back then wait between retries until it hits 20. It uses your connection string timeout in the calculation of how often to retry.

Are you seeing failures even after 20 retries? Is your workflow hosted in WCF or are you invoking it manually?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for this. We can control the count by writing a custom workflowcommitworkbatch service class and add this in your web.config services section. You can write your own logic into it ! – user1722059 just now   edit